# Make floated div fill remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make `left` div fill remaining space? In general, what I want to accomplish is to set right div to the right and fill remaining space with left div.

```html
<div>
  <div id="left" style="float: left"></div>
  <div id="right" style="float: right; max-width: 700px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use table? Or css `display` of divs as of a table.

Comment: Don't want to use `table` tag. I thought there is more "natural" way.

Comment: display:table/table-cell; do not require table tags but uses the table display properties (css 2.1 spec from 1998) ;) do not mix CSS and HTMl (for instance defaut display of <li> is display:list-item; that you can apply to any else tags than LI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#right {
  max-width: 700px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    Left left left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    Right right right
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a guide for css flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/